# How to tell Agda to unfold a definition to prove an equivalency

Tags: agda

I have a function like this:

```
open import Data.Char
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Bool
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality.≡-Reasoning

foo : Char → Char → ℕ
foo c1 c2 with c1 == c2
... | true = 123
... | false = 456
```

I would like to prove that when I call it with the same argument (`foo c c`), it always yields `123`:

```
foo-eq⇒123 : ∀ (c : Char) → foo c c ≡ 123
foo-eq⇒123 c =
  foo c c ≡⟨ {!!} ⟩
  123 ∎
```

I am able to use `refl` to prove a trivial example:

```
foo-example : foo 'a' 'a' ≡ 123
foo-example = refl
```

So, I would think that I could just put `refl` in the hole since all Agda needs to do is beta-reduce `foo c c`. However, replacing the hole with `refl` yields the following error:

```
.../Unfold.agda:15,14-18
(foo c c
 | Relation.Nullary.Decidable.Core.isYes
   (Relation.Nullary.Decidable.Core.map′ Data.Char.Properties.≈⇒≡
    Data.Char.Properties.≈-reflexive
    (Relation.Nullary.Decidable.Core.map′
     (Data.Nat.Properties.≡ᵇ⇒≡ (toℕ c) (toℕ c))
     (Data.Nat.Properties.≡⇒≡ᵇ (toℕ c) (toℕ c)) (T? (toℕ c ≡ᵇ toℕ c)))))
!= 123 of type ℕ
when checking that the expression refl has type foo c c ≡ 123
```

I suspect the issue is that Agda doesn't automatically understand that `c == c` is `true` for all `c`:

```
c==c : ∀ (c : Char) → (c == c) ≡ true
c==c c = refl
```

```
.../Unfold.agda:23,10-14
Relation.Nullary.Decidable.Core.isYes
(Relation.Nullary.Decidable.Core.map′ Data.Char.Properties.≈⇒≡
 Data.Char.Properties.≈-reflexive
 (Relation.Nullary.Decidable.Core.map′
  (Data.Nat.Properties.≡ᵇ⇒≡ (toℕ c) (toℕ c))
  (Data.Nat.Properties.≡⇒≡ᵇ (toℕ c) (toℕ c)) (T? (toℕ c ≡ᵇ toℕ c))))
!= true of type Bool
when checking that the expression refl has type (c == c) ≡ true
```

So, what is the right way to prove my `foo-eq⇒123` theorem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agda's built-in `Char` type is a little weird. Let's contrast it with a non-weird built-in type, `ℕ`. The equality test for `ℕ` looks as follows.

```
_≡ᵇ_ : Nat → Nat → Bool
zero  ≡ᵇ zero  = true
suc n ≡ᵇ suc m = n ≡ᵇ m
_     ≡ᵇ _     = false
```

Note that `n ≡ᵇ n` doesn't reduce to `true`, either. After all, Agda doesn't know whether `n` is `zero` or `suc`, i.e., which of the two clauses to apply for the reduction. So, this has the same problem as your `Char` example. But for `ℕ` there is an easy way out.

Let's look at your example again and let's also add a `ℕ`-based version of `foo`, `bar`.

```
open import Data.Char using (Char ; _==_ ; _≟_)
open import Data.Nat using (ℕ ; zero ; suc ; _≡ᵇ_)
open import Data.Bool using (true ; false)
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality using (_≡_ ; refl)
open import Relation.Nullary using (yes ; no)
open import Relation.Nullary.Negation using (contradiction)

foo : Char → Char → ℕ
foo c1 c2 with c1 == c2
... | true  = 123
... | false = 456

bar : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ
bar n1 n2 with n1 ≡ᵇ n2
... | true  = 123
... | false = 456
```

So, what's the easy way out for `ℕ`? We pattern match / do a case split on `n` to reduce `n ≡ᵇ n` *just enough* to do our proof. I.e., either to the base case `zero` or to the next recursive step `suc n`.

```
bar-eq⇒123 : ∀ n → bar n n ≡ 123
bar-eq⇒123 zero    = refl
bar-eq⇒123 (suc n) = bar-eq⇒123 n
```

`ℕ` just has two constructors and we know what `≡ᵇ` looks like, so pattern matching is straight forward.

For `Char`, things are way more complicated. Long story short, the equality test for `Char` is defined in terms of a function `toℕ` that Agda doesn't give us a definition for. Also, the `Char` data type is postulated and doesn't come with any constructors. So a proof like `bar-eq⇒123` is not an option for `Char`. We don't have clauses and we don't have constructors. (I wouldn't call, say, `'a'` a constructor for `Char`. Similarly to how `1234` is not a constructor for `ℕ`.)

So, what *could* we do? Note that `c == c` in the error message that you quoted reduces to something pretty complicated that involves `isYes`. If we reduced `c == c` only a tiny little bit (instead of as much as possible), we'd get `isYes (c ≟ c)` (instead of the complicated thing from the error message).

`_≟_` is the decidable equality for `Char` (i.e., a combination of an "Equal or not?" Boolean and a proof). `isYes` strips away the proof and gives us the Boolean.

My idea for a proof would then be to not do a case split on `c` (as we did for `ℕ`), but on `c ≟ c`. This would yield two cases and reduce the `isYes` to `true` or `false`, respectively. The `true` case would be obvious. The `false` case could be dicharged by contradiction with the proof from the decidable equality.

```
foo-eq⇒123 : ∀ c → foo c c ≡ 123
foo-eq⇒123 c with c ≟ c
... | yes p = refl
... | no ¬p = contradiction refl ¬p
```

Note that, in turn, this proof doesn't easily translate to `ℕ`, as `_≡ᵇ_` isn't based on decidable equality and `isYes`. It's a primitive instead.

Maybe an even better idea would be to consistently stick to decidable equality, for `Char` as well as `ℕ` instead of using `_==_` or `_≡ᵇ_`. `foo` would then look as follows.

```
baz : Char → Char → ℕ
baz c1 c2 with c1 ≟ c2
... | yes p = 123
... | no ¬p = 456
```

And the `foo-eq⇒123` proof would apply to it unchanged.